# How to calculate minimum number of quantity as well as a break even point

Tags: derivatives, economics

The daily cost of producing $q$ in a manufacture company is $$c = 5000 + 100q.$$
1) If each item is sold for $\$200$, how can I calculate the minimum quantity without any loss?

$$200q - (5000 + 100q) = 100q +5000 = 50.$$ is this correct?

2) Also, if the price is up by $10$ Dollars per unit, how can I calculate the break even point? 
$$100 + 10 = 110, 110q - (5000 + 100q) = 500$$ is this correct?

Comment: For $1$ if you mean $q=50$ that seems correct. I have no idea what $2$ is meant to say.

Comment: When you say "sold for" do you mean this is the profit or does this price include the production cost?

Comment: for No2, if the price to sell the item is increased by that price, i want to know the break even point

Comment: for "sold for" , have no idea with the details but if the item is sold at that price, i want to know the minimum quantity to be produced and sold without any loss. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You break even when the sales income for the quantity $q$ equals the cost of production for the same quantity $q$.

**Case 1**

$$cost=5000+100q$$
$$SalesIncome=200q$$

Break point is for $q$ to satisfy:

%%

$$Cost=SalesIncome$$

$$5000+100q = 200q$$

so,
$$5000=100q$$

and hence $$q=5000/100=50$$

That is you need to sell 50 items to break even.

**Case 2**

When the price goes up by $10$ Dollars, the price becomes $210$

Break point is for $q$ to satisfy:
$$5000+100q = 210q$$

so,
$$5000+100q = 210q-100q=10q$$

Hence the quantity is $500$ units to break even.

This picture shows case 1:

[image]

Comment: thank you so my answers are both correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand your equations.

Comment: you mean No2 equation? well i just calculate the numbers because i am not familiar with the correct equation so maybe thats why it looks strange...

Comment: No, I mean the way you obtained the solution is not very clear to me.

Comment: Can i ask which one?

Comment: Both are very brief....However the 2nd one is not clear - What is 100+10=....?

Comment: Very sorry. my bad...what i meant is 200 + 10 = 210...